# Stored procedure executes but does not update data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure in a SQL Server 2005 database that's accessed by ASP.NET / C# code.

The parameters for the stored procedure are defined in the typical manner:

```
Try
{

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mystoredprocedure",myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1"), SqlDbType.Int))
cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = myvalue (usually form inputs)

.
.
.

myConnection.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

}
catch (Exception xx)
{
lblError.Text = xx.Message;
}
finally
{
myConnection.Close();
}
```

The problem is my data never updates, though the stored procedure doesn't throw any errors. I've checked the procedure in SQL Server, and when I call it directly through SQL Server the proc makes my updates.

I'm tearing my hair out on this one since it worked fine for a long time, then stopped working. I've checked the usual culprits (db connection is pointing to the right database, the procedure seems to work fine in SQL Server, and I've commented out the few new parameters I've created)

Any thoughts on what could be causing this? It's strange that the same procedure works in SQL Server but not through my code without throwing any errors. (To be sure, I put a return value in the stored procedure, and the return value indicates I'm not rolling back)

**EDIT**

Code for the stored procedure:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --get count
update dbo.myTable set 
 val1=@val1,
 val2=@val2,
.
.
.

WHERE ID=@MyID

SET @Err = @@ERROR

--if error rollback transaction
IF @Err <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        GOTO ErrorHandler
    END
Select @ReturnCode = 1
COMMIT TRANSACTION

RETURN

ErrorHandler:
--unknown error
Select @ReturnCode = 0
RAISERROR (@Err, 16, 1 ) WITH LOG
RETURN -100
```

**EDIT**

When I parse cmd.ExecuteNonQuery, I get -1 as a result. Still trying to figure out why the C# code is doing this but not throwing any errors. Shouldn't ExecuteNonQuery return the number of rows affected by the stored procedure?

**EDIT**

Using TFS I've stepped back in my history a couple of revs - it seems like there's an additional field I added recently that's breaking the query. When I comment out that field and call my sproc, it works fine.

I don't get why, though - it's just a varchar(255) field. I've got plenty of other fields in this database that are set up in similar ways. Any thoughts as to why this would be a problem?

**EDIT**
Using SQL Profiler, I can see the statement execute AND commit...but still, no data updates. I'm wondering whether I need to trash the sproc and start over again?

Comment: What's tell you SQL Profiler ? What is the call ? Is your parameter is transmited ?

Comment: is there a transaction (maybe via `TransactionScope`) involved? Are you perhaps running against a database *file*, and then discarding the copy in bin/debug each time you build?

Comment: Where is SP code? Is there any ambient transactions around this code?

Comment: Please post the entire SP, what are the parameters expected ?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary in profiler...it shows me the code for the procedure, says it's been executed, and committed, but no data update.

Comment: In edit, you said "an additional field I added", does it means you have added a column to table being updated in stored proc? If it's so, please check if column is nullable or not, there must be value for not-null columns.

Comment: Does your connection string include the word `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: please can you post the full c# parameter code as well as the full SP code.

Comment: Did you solve your problem, can you post your solution @Tim ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the stored procedure without the .Net code (i.e directly in SQL Server Management Studio) and see whether the changes are updated or not. Probably you are missing an explicit `commit` statement.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like an uncommitted transaction to me as well.

Comment: Usually the SQL-Server is in autocommit mode. so if you close the connection, it will execute a commit.

Comment: When I do this, the code runs fine and makes my updates. I've got an explicit commit in the procedure. I'll post a snippet of the procedure code.

Comment: Okay then next step is to see the profiler to trace what values are being passed. Generally(90% of times) it happens that you look at wrong connection , or wrong dataset or you have missed commits.
it could be same for you, or it could be something really big issue :D

Comment: Also could you put some more debug lines in your code(SP), to see if all the lines are executed or not. Weather it goes to the error handler or not. You have to debug it step by step cancelling out all the possiblities at each step

Answer (score 2):

May sound stupid, but if you are out of disk space I've seen SQL server go through the motions, no errors but your data does not get saved. Easy to check too!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `CommandType` like that :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mystoredprocedure",myConnection)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Comment: If this was the issue, we would expect a big noticeable exception to hit the `catch` block

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
SqlCommand cmd;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

or you maybe use:

```
CALL mystoredprocedure(@ParameterName)
```

as SQL-Text

Comment: If this was the issue, we would expect a big noticeable exception to hit the `catch` block

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("mystoredprocedure('{0}')",inputValue),myConnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run sp directly from SQL SERVER and remove error handling from stored procedure to get the exact error in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try one simple thing for me?

Change your stored procedure to accept no parameter. Change logic of stored proc to just insert one row in one table and then change your code to call that procedure and find out whether call is successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use a wrong way to call a stored procedure. The value -1 returned by ExecuteNonQuery is because of the statement: if INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE the value is the number of rows affected, -1 if there's a rollback. In all the other cases the return value is -1 (your case, I think).

The SqlCommand constructor when used with the two parameters SqlCommand(String, SqlConnection) needs that the first one is a generic query so you can run something like "exec myProcedure @par1" and the parameters can be set e.g.:

```
Dim par1 As New SqlParameter("@par1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
par1.Value = "DummyValue"
cmd.Parameters.Add(par1)
```

But in the ideal situation, when you've to call a stored than you've to set the CommandType to "StoredProcedure", like then MSDN suggests in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/yy6y35y8.aspx.

(I will show you VB code... sorry.. it's easily converted to C# with tools like [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).)

If you want to read a value from the stored procedure that you run, you can populate a datased (for example, "ds") using a SqlAdapter -this is only an example-:

```
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "result")

        If ds.Tables.Item("result").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
```

If you don't need to read anything you can simply use:

```
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Surely you've to tell that you want to launch a stored procedure:

```
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Hope to be useful to you...

Bye, Massimo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing Command Type while creating Command object.. Set command type of command object as StoreProcegure and then check again.. Since if u dont set command type then ur query execute but u wont get any error and required result also.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see that the parameter name you are passing is not the same that you are using in you procedure.